# Multithreading program doesn't finish the job correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading

So, like the question tile. I'm trying to learn multithreading programming. I have a awkward program to hlep me understand multithreading is faster than regular execution. The programm has seven classes in one java file, one test class, three classes implement Runnable, and three regular classes. The six classes all do the same thing, counting to 10 millions and return result. My problem is the three classes using three threads to run, but they didn't return the correct counts as I expected. However the three regular classes work fine.

I really appreciate anyone can help me to understand why it happens! I using JDK 9 and Eclipse 2018-12.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

class MyMultiThreadExample{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GameOne g1 = new GameOne();
        GameTwo g2 = new GameTwo();
        GameThree g3 = new GameThree();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(g1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(g2);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(g3);

        Instant start1 = Instant.now();

        thread1.start();

        thread2.start();

        thread3.start();

        Instant end1 = Instant.now();

        long elapsed = Duration.between(start1, end1).toMillis();

        int total = g1.getCount() + g2.getCount() + g3.getCount();

        System.out.println("MultiThread running cost " + elapsed + " to count " + total + " times");

        GameFour g4 = new GameFour();
        GameFive g5 = new GameFive();
        GameSix g6 = new GameSix();

        Instant start2 = Instant.now();

        g4.run();
        g5.run();
        g6.run();

        Instant end2 = Instant.now();

        long elapsed2 = Duration.between(start2, end2).toMillis();

        int total2 = g3.getCount() + g4.getCount() + g5.getCount();

        System.out.println("Sequential running cost " + elapsed2 + " to count " + total2 + " times");
    }

}
```

```
class GameOne implements Runnable {

    int count1 = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // System.out.print("Game1 at round " + count + " now");
            count1++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("GameOne counts " + count1);
        return count1;
    }
}
```

```
class GameTwo implements Runnable {

    int count2 = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // System.out.print("Game2 at round " + count + " now");
            count2++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("GameTwo counts " + count2);
        return count2;
    }
}
```

```
class GameThree implements Runnable {

    int count3 = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // System.out.print("Game3 at round " + count + " now");
            count3++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("GameThree counts " + count3);
        return count3;
    }
}
```

```
class GameFour {

    int count4 = 0;

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // System.out.print("Game3 at round " + count + " now");
            count4++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("GameFour counts " + count4);
        return count4;
    }
}
```

```
class GameFive {

    int count5 = 0;

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // System.out.print("Game3 at round " + count + " now");
            count5++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("GameFive counts " + count5);
        return count5;
    }
}
```

```
class GameSix {

    int count6 = 0;

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // System.out.print("Game3 at round " + count + " now");
            count6++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("GameFive counts " + count6);
        return count6;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to call `thread.join()` -- this waits until the thread finishes executing.

Otherwise you're reading the `counter`s in the middle of the execution.

Your code should be:

```
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
thread3.join()
```

Additionally, all your classes can be compacted into a single `class Game`:

```
class Game implements Runnable {
    String name;
    int count = 0;

    public Game(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // System.out.print(name + " at round " + count + " now");
            count++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println(name + " counts " + count);
        return count;
    }
}
```

Each will have its own counter, and you can run them in a thread or in the same thread by calling `run()` -- your main method remains mostly unchanged except where they're instantiated. They can be instantiated like:

```
Game g1 = new Game("GameOne");
Game g2 = new Game("GameTwo");
Game g3 = new Game("GameThree");
Game g4 = new Game("GameFour");
Game g5 = new Game("GameFive");
Game g6 = new Game("GameSix");
```

Comment: Thank you J. I realize those six funny class after I posted this question and should be written like you said.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a awkward program to hlep me understand multithreading is faster than regular execution.

It's important to understand this is not always the case. You should only use multiple Threads when you have long running tasks that can run in parallel. IF your tasks are short, they almost certainly will run faster by running on a single Thread as there's an overhead on creating an specially synchronizing between Threads.

With that out of the way, you are not actually measuring the correct time here.

When you call `Thread.start()`, it will run the relevant `Runnable` in parallel with the code inside your function.

To let the Threads run until they complete before proceeding, you must call `Thread#join()`:

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();

// all 3 Threads may be running now, but maybe not even started!
// let's wait for them to finish running by joining them
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
thread3.join();
```

This is the easiest way to wait... but there are others and this is a complex topic.

You may also run into trouble as your tasks have mutable state (the `count` variables) and the visibility of changes from different Threads needs to be carefully managed (you can make it volatile, for example, so updates are flushed to other Threads).

To learn more about concurrency in Java, I recommend you read about it. The [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrency) tutorials are excellent.